# Linking verbs with passive voice, or not?

Tags: passive-voice, linking-verbs

Here I am again.

Well, cutting to the chase: I was reading about linking verbs and saw an example: **Opportunity is missed by most people**, so one question arose: Are all statements in passive voice used with complements?

Check it:

1. **I sent a letter**
2. **A letter was sent**

In the first example, **send** is a transitive verb taking a direct object (**letter**).

In the second example, **was** is a linking verb, and **sent** is acting as an adjective.

So, I realized that no passive voice can be used with a direct object, does it mean that they are always used with subject complements, is it right?

Comment: Sorry, but I see _sent_ as a verb. _A closed door_ has an adjective. _A door was closed_ has the passive verb phrase 'was closed.' If you do your best to avoid the passive voice, you will be doing yourself a favor.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - In some cases, passive voice is required, and I need to be ready for them, haha.
However, I also found it weird, but someone said that they are called: Participle adjectives; I do think that they are used specially for passive voices, for they act exactly as an adjective.

Comment: In _A letter was sent_, 'was' is used as an auxiliary to effect the passive voice, not in its linking role (_John was cold_). Yes, sometimes there is ambiguity (_The window was broken_), but not in this case. And not with _Opportunity is missed by most people_ (again a passive construction).

Comment: @Yosef Baskin The passive voice is vastly favourable to the active in some circumstances; advice to totally avoid it is poor.

Comment: @Haseo Your terminology confuses your ideas here. Passive constructions **always** have an auxiliary verb -- some form of _be_ -- and that is **always** followed by the past participle of the verb (_missed, sent_ ). These are not adjectives; these are verbs, because the passive construction is the last part of the auxiliary verb chain, and each auxiliary verb must be followed by a particular verb form.

Comment: @JohnLawler - So you are saying that passive voice constructions follow a different pattern? A normal sentence's pattern would be: *Subject, Verb or Linking verb, Object or Complement..*, whereas the passive voice construction's pattern would be: *Subject (which was turned from objecto into subject), Auxiliary verb (Be), and Past participle?*

Therefore, since it follows a different pattern, we can't similar it to other sentence's construction, right?

Comment: No. I'm saying you don't understand the regular pattern (the one you present is not close to adequate; your textbook or teacher is deficient, I'm afraid), so you can't understand how passive constructions differ from it. All passive constructions have an auxiliary verb _be_ (not a 'linking verb", which is gradeschool terminology) followed immediately by the past participle of the active verb (_is written, was seen, has been read, will be released, must have been killed_, etc.). The _be_ of Passive is the last auxiliary verb of the verb chain and may be preceded by other auxiliaries.

Comment: @JohnLawler - And in what does it differ from what I said? *Be* is a linking verb and also acts as an auxiliar, what is the necessity to call someone a deficient because they use different terms? Besides, Longman's grammar book also calls it a linking verb and an auxiliar.
In this sentence: **John is an architect**, **Is** isn't acting as an auxiliar; it is a linking verb specifying one relation between the noun (architect) and the subject (John).

Anyway, I got what you meant; it is actually what I was trying to say.
Best regards.

Comment: _Be_ is always an auxiliary verb. When the main predicate is an adjective or a noun instead of a main verb, _be_ is the auxiliary verb required: _He is a doctor, She is tired, That is straw_. Calling it a "linking verb" doesn't make it any different.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Again: That's what I was trying to say: different names, same things. Anyway, check it: http://grammar-monster.com/glossary/linking_verbs.htm - In the final of the article, it says: **He was happy.
He is happy.
Therefore, the "to be" part of a passive construction (here, was painted) and a verb tense (here, is frustrating) can be considered a linking verb.** - So, it could possibly be considered to be a linking verb, both parts: (was painted) and (is frustrating).

Comment: Unfortunately, "linking verb" is used to mean both the same thing as "auxiliary verb", and different uses as well, so that it's confusing. There is no "linkage" between a predicate noun or adjective and its subject; the auxiliary verb is there to be inflected and to mark the construction. It has no meaning or function besides that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence '*Opportunity is missed by most people*', there is no linking verb. It is an example of a passive sentence. The active form of it is, *'Most people miss opportunity'*. The verb is 'miss' and its passive equivalent is formed by the auxiliary **is + past participle** of 'miss'.

> "A copular verb (also called  [linking verb](https://www.englishgrammar.org/copular-verbs/)) is a special kind of
>   verb used to join an adjective or noun complement to a subject. 
>   Common examples are: be (is, am, are, was, were), appear, seem, look,
>   sound, smell, taste, feel, become and get".

All participle forms (present or past participle) can act as adjectives when they modify nouns.

> In the sentence ***'A letter was sent***', the verb is not 'was'
>   alone. It is the verb phrase 'was sent' (the passive voice formed
>   using the auxiliary **was + Past participle** of 'send').

Example: You prepared 10 letters. You sent 5 letters or Five letters were sent. You have five letters remaining.

Now you can classify as: Some are **sent letters** and others are **remaining letters**.

The verb **'are'** here is a **linking verb** and **'sent'** and **'remaining'** are **adjectives** - the former past participle and the latter present participle.

> Direct or indirect object can also be changed to subject of the
>   passive sentences.
>
> I gave you a letter. (Active Voice, you = I O, a letter =D O)
>
> You **were given** a letter. -Passive.
>
> A letter **was given** to you. -Passive.

Comment: I got your point, mahmud; I was actually confused about the pattern of the passive voice, I wasn't considering *be + past participle* to be acting as one verb, where *to be* is acting as an auxiliary and the *past participle* the main verb. This was confusing me; it can't be thought as a normal pattern since it follows a different one. Thank you :)